# Using scipy.odeint with different time step

Tags: python, ode, odeint

I am testing using scipy.integrate.odeint with different time steps.

Specifically, I setup a 1D diffusion simulation with particles at one end diffusing to the other side. For diffusion I use a finite difference second derivative approximation.

Surprisingly I am getting different simulation results depending on the time step taken, even if the total simulation time is the same.

```
import scipy
import scipy.integrate
import numpy as np
import sys

num_bins=40
bin_size=0.01
bin_size2=bin_size*bin_size
mol_scale=1e-9


def step(y, t, d,dt):
    dnorm=(d*dt)/(bin_size2)
    dydt=np.zeros([num_bins])
    for i in range(1,num_bins-1):
        dydt[i]=(y[i-1]-2*y[i]+y[i+1])*dnorm
    dydt[0]=(-y[0]+y[1])*dnorm
    dydt[num_bins-1]=(y[num_bins-2]-y[num_bins-1])*dnorm
    return dydt

y0=np.zeros([num_bins])
y0[1]=1000*mol_scale

d1=0.001
d2=0.01
d3=0.1
#dt1=1
dt=0.01
num_mins=2
t2 = np.linspace(0, num_mins, int((60*num_mins)/dt)+1) #second intervals
sol1 = scipy.integrate.odeint(step, y0, t2, args=(d1,dt))
sol2 = scipy.integrate.odeint(step, y0, t2, args=(d2,dt))
sol3 = scipy.integrate.odeint(step, y0, t2, args=(d3,dt))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tp=-1
plt.plot(range(num_bins), sol1[tp, :]/mol_scale, 'b', label='sol1')
plt.plot(range(num_bins), sol2[tp, :]/mol_scale, 'g', label='sol2')
plt.plot(range(num_bins), sol3[tp, :]/mol_scale, 'r', label='sol3')

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('x')


plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

When dt=1 (1 second), I get the following signal distribution at the end of 2 minutes simulation.

[Signal profile after two minutes simulation with dt=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3eKi.png)

However, when dt=0.1 (0.1 second), I get a different signal distribution.

[Signal profile after two minutes simulation with dt=0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jitox.png)

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Keren.

Comment: The time discretization happens in the ODE integrator. There is no place for `dt` in the step function. It is common to find `dt/dx^2` as a factor, but then this happens on a simultaneous space and time discretization.